# jQuery - showing control handles on image (i.e. transform manager)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a transform manager in jQuery/HTML5 or not? Is there something which at least shows control handles around the image/div upon clicking?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [jQuery UI Dialog class](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). The Dialog class give you different handles (scale, move etc).  I'm assuming that is what you meant by "Control Handles". You could do some cool transformation onclick of a div into a Dialog and then when the div loses focus, go back to a normal div.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but If I get a control handle around the div or image so that I can re-size it from any corner .